# Mostrar un DataTable al tener seleccionado una opción de un DropDownList

Tags: javascript, datatables

Tengo un Datatable en html hecho en js y tengo un DropDownList que quiero que al seleccionar una opción pueda mostrar **solo las filas que tengan ese dato** mediante un botón. Al principio pensé en una extracción de cada valor seleccionado, por ejemplo el option seleccionado del DropDownList y de la columna en la cual se encuentra esa opción, para después mostrar el datatable pero con el filtro implementado. Pude extraer el valor del DropDownList pero no he podido encontrar una forma de obtener el valor del dato buscado en el datatable.

Comment: Tu título difiere levemente del cuerpo de tu pregunta. ¿Te referís a [esto](https://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html)?

Comment: tienes razón, difiere un poco, es mi primera pregunta por acá y me costó explicar la idea. El objetivo es ese pero mi problema es que yo cargo el datatable mediante una función en C# que me devuelve un JSON con todos los datos correspondientes a sus respectivas columnas, después lo uso en un script para armar el datatable y el DropDown lo creó en C# sin tener que pasar los datos en un JSON entonces a la hora de vincularlos parte el problema.